# Publishing filters on cartoDB map

Tags: carto, carto-js, user-interface

I want users to interact with my CartoDB map by interacting with filters. The CartoDB Editor allows to filter data but there doesn't appear to be an option to "expose" the filters to the end-user. Is this something that requires some custom CartoDB.JS scripting or am I missing something ?

The only available user interface options on published maps are toggling through layers and a "search box" in which I am not sure what I am searching.

Lastly, any place where I can find CartoDB driven interfaces i.e. a CartoDB map with custom JS scripting on top of the map content ?

Answer (score 1):

I was also trying to allow the end-user to use the CartoDB filters, but I was not able to find a way to directly do that. My solution was to add drop-down menus to [my map](http://mappingancienttexts.net/visualizations/cassiope/), so that the end-user can click on a drop-down menu and select an attribute to filter by (e.g. click the Author menu and then click the Cicero option). The drop-down menu is filled with buttons that carry out SQL statements. I used a modified form of [this](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/toggle_map_view/) to make the buttons.